Apache VirtualHost configuration file
I have installed Apache on Ubuntu and want to publish a simple website.
But I dont understand where to put the configuration for my wep page.
Pleas help

/var/www/html/ or you could use the user directory http://servername/~username which i think is in /home/username/~htdocs

By default:

Your public files are in: /var/www/html

The default configuration file for the Apache web server: /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf


